# Expandable UITextField with option for inserting image

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uitextview

I want to make the same view as iPhone default message app here is the screen shot what i want to do so can any one help me for suggesting 3rd party control or technique for making this kind of control in my app

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Source code you wanted for the Growing TextField , although it doesn't contains the image button but you can easily customize it to fullfil your requirement

https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the image view as a subView of UITextView.

Create an imageView with image:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:yourImage];
[imageView setFrame:yourFrame];
[yourTextView addSubview:imageView];
```

and can use third party library for this [Here](https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks for the reply i did that but and i am getting this response http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=t9ih69&s=5 the text having there on property while the image is on the front of it. how ever in the default message control the text is up or down to the image.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly add your image view on text view.
Tried this one

```
    UIImageView * image=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xyz.png"]];

    [textview addSubview:image];
```

this will really helpful.