# iOS Add Image to TextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am experimenting a little bit witch apps programming.
How I can add a UIImage to a UITextField"?
Like Whats App or the most other Chat Apps.
I have search some time but doesn't find a solution, also i have tried to search in side of XCode with the auto complete but I have not found a function. So I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to add an image to a text field is to have a UIView that contains *both* UITextField and a UIImageView as subviews.

Next up, you can have a [UIButton with both an image and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717219/uibutton-image-text-ios), and just set `userInteractionEnabled` to "NO" and it'll behave like a text view with an image next to it.

Now to get more complicated, if you want a chat-like text field that allows text (that you can type into) and images next to each other, you need to start thinking about custom subclasses. [Other people have asked and have gotten answers for this same approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399506/expandable-uitextfield-with-option-for-inserting-image).